# distinct over multilple columns technique

Tags: mysql

Is this a good way to do a distinct over 3 columns?
Basically I want to have a unique list of the combination of 3 columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(field1 , field2, field3), field1 , field2, field3 from mytable;

CREATE TABLE test ( ID INT NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY, field1
int, field2 int, field3 int );

**Given:** 
1 2 1 
1 2 2 
1 2 1 
1 4 5 
1 2 2

**I want:** 
1 2 1 
1 2 2 
1 4 5
```

Comment: i believe if you group bu the three columns, it should show you the distinct, but i might be wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do -

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1 , field2, field3 from mytable;
```

or

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 from mytable
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
```